# Error install imapsync

Tags: 14.04

I got this error install Imapsync

```
perl -c imapsync || { echo; echo "Read the INSTALL file to solve Perl module dependencies!"; exit 1; }
Can't locate IO/Tee.pm in @INC (you may need to install the IO::Tee module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at imapsync line 591.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at imapsync line 591.

Read the INSTALL file to solve Perl module dependencies!
make: *** [testp] Fout 1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**imapsync** on 16.04 Xenial (on a fresh/basic install) do:

```
 sudo apt-get install libio-tee-perl
 sudo apt-get install libmail-imapclient-perl
 sudo apt-get install libterm-readkey-perl
 sudo apt-get install libunicode-string-perl

 ## The rest is optional I believe:

 sudo apt-get install libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl
 sudo apt-get install libauthen-ntlm-perl
 sudo apt-get install libdata-uniqid-perl
 sudo apt-get install libjson-perl
 sudo apt-get install liblwp-online-perl

 ## For Xenial/16.04 I could not locate these packages nor would 'cpan'
 ## work for me - but you could try (as user running imapsync):
 cpan install JSON::WebToken
 cpan install Filesys::DfPortable
```

Then test:

```
 ./imapsync --dry --host1 localhost --user1 1@localhost --password1 1 --host2 localhost --user2 2@localhost --password2 2
```

You should see a module list within the error output:

```
Modules version list:
Mail::IMAPClient     3.38
IO::Socket           1.38
IO::Socket::IP       0.37
IO::Socket::INET     1.35
IO::Socket::SSL      2.024
Net::SSLeay          1.72
Compress::Zlib       2.068
Digest::MD5          2.54
Digest::HMAC_MD5     1.01
Digest::HMAC_SHA1    1.03
Term::ReadKey        2.33
File::Spec           3.56
Time::HiRes          1.9726
Unicode::String      2.09
IO::Tee              0.64
File::Copy::Recursive 0.38
Authen::NTLM         1.09
URI::Escape          3.31
Data::Uniqid         0.12
JSON                 2.90
JSON::WebToken       ?
Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA  0.28
LWP                  6.15
HTML::Entities       3.69
Filesys::DfPortable  ?
```

I can confirm the imap sync worked using the above package installs on 14.04/16.04 Dovecot systems using TLS. As I mentioned, you may only need the first ones listed to get it working at a basic level. The perl modules needed should be basically the same under 14.04 fresh install.

Answer (score 2):

There was a dependency added for logging.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libio-tee-perl
```

You may also need:

```
sudo apt-get install libunicode-string-perl
```